# Not displaying Flash message on logout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to display a flash message when a user logs out, but for some reason its not working. Please help me in fixing this

```js
// Logout
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout((err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
  req.flash("success_msg", "You are logged out");
  res.redirect("/users/login");
});
```

Comment: Do you have `connect-flash` installed and configured?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichałSadowski yes I have installed connect-flash